# Error loading own data set. numClasses and InputSplit

Tags: java, dataset, deeplearning4j, dl4j

Unexpected exception when load own dataset. The execution of the code from [FeaturizedPreSave](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/transferlearning/vgg16/dataHelpers/FeaturizedPreSave.java) with just a minor change in the number of samples to be taken into consideration for the neural network produce an exception of Unsupported Operation.

```
numClasses = 96
```

instead of the initial 5. And own [DataSet](https://vk.com/doc108308742_467339969).

Error:

> Reader output: 96 output classes, but array.size (1) is 58
>   (must be equal to 1 or numClasses = 96).

**Version Information:**

- Deeplearning4j 1.0.0-alpha
- CUDA 8
- Java 8

Trace:

- [error_trace](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/error_trace)
- [log_trace](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/log_trace)

Comment: Are you sure that the only change committed by you is the numclasses? Check if the dataset that you use has 96 classes.

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila , I sure. Only numClasses and Dataset.

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila Oh, I use `ZooModel zooModel = VGG16(); ` instead of `ZooModel zooModel = VGG16.builder().build(); `.
Could this be the cause of the error?

Comment: I'm recently start use ZooModel, so Im not a pro, but to initialing fresh networks is this way: `Model net = zooModel.init();`. More docs [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/model-zoo)

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like there are 58 examples in the test set. So perhaps you've swapped your axes somewhere.

Comment: Also I have this messege:
`15:05:12,830 INFO  ~ trainData 230
15:05:12,830 INFO  ~ testData 58
15:05:12,838 INFO  ~ numExamples 6011
15:05:12,838 INFO  ~ numLabels 96`
I decided to check what data it receives

Answer (score 0):

That's my fault! I did not change the size of the images in new dataset.